# Как сравнить значение в таблицах

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть таблица, у которой есть поле bigint[]. В этом поле лежат несколько чисел. Я бы хотел построить запрос, в котором я смотрю совпадает мое число с каким то из этих значений
К примеру,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (my_bigint_array)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select true where 1 = ANY (ARRAY[1,2,3]);`  - True

`select true where 1 = ANY (ARRAY[2,3]);`  - False

Оператор `ANY` вернет `true` если хотя бы один элемент в массиве будет равен единице.

Ваш запрос:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ANY (my_bigint_array)`

Comment: `ANY` это **не функция** - так что всегда ставьте пробел между этим словом и открывающей скобкой.